# multi-column factorize in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, enumeration, data-cleaning

The pandas `factorize` function assigns each unique value in a series to a sequential, 0-based index, and calculates which index each series entry belongs to.

I'd like to accomplish the equivalent of `pandas.factorize` on multiple columns:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1], 'y':[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]})
pd.factorize(df)[0] # would like [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0]
```

That is, I want to determine each unique tuple of values in several columns of a data frame, assign a sequential index to each, and compute which index each row in the data frame belongs to.

`Factorize` only works on single columns. Is there a multi-column equivalent function in pandas?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: the list in the comment -- a unique, sequential index for each distinct (x, y) value

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to create a ndarray of tuple first, `pandas.lib.fast_zip` can do this very fast in cython loop.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1], 'y':[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]})
print pd.factorize(pd.lib.fast_zip([df.x, df.y]))[0]
```

the output is:

```
[0 1 2 2 1 0]
```

Comment: Thanks -- that gives the answer I'm looking for, in a reasonably compact form

Comment: I get the following error: {AttributeError}module 'pandas' has no attribute 'lib'

Comment: The function can be found under ``pd._libs.lib.fast_zip``. Not sure when it changed.

Comment: you need to use `df.x.values` and `df.y.values` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23434439/3965888)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is an efficient solution. There might be better solutions for this.

```
arr=[] #this will hold the unique items of the dataframe
for i in df.index:
   if list(df.iloc[i]) not in arr:
      arr.append(list(df.iloc[i]))
```

so printing the arr would give you

```
>>>print arr
[[1,1],[1,2],[2,2]]
```

to hold the indices, i would declare an ind array

```
ind=[]
for i in df.index:
   ind.append(arr.index(list(df.iloc[i])))
```

printing ind would give

```
 >>>print ind
 [0,1,2,2,1,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drop_duplicates` to drop those duplicated rows

```
In [23]: df.drop_duplicates()
Out[23]: 
      x  y
   0  1  1
   1  1  2
   2  2  2
```

## EDIT

To achieve your goal, you can join your original df to the drop_duplicated one:

```
In [46]: df.join(df.drop_duplicates().reset_index().set_index(['x', 'y']), on=['x', 'y'])
Out[46]: 
   x  y  index
0  1  1      0
1  1  2      1
2  2  2      2
3  2  2      2
4  1  2      1
5  1  1      0
```

Comment: I'm not looking to drop them, but to assign a unique index to each pair of distinct values (i.e. I eventually want to add a new column to the data frame, with values [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0]).

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1], 'y':[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]})
tuples = df[['x', 'y']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
df['newID'] = pd.factorize( tuples )[0]
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does differently from OP's and how that solves the problem. I recommend this guide on creating a useful answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer