# pandas: bad argument to internal function ( in iterators.c)

Tags: python, pandas

Why do I get an error here? Using Python 2.6 and pandas v.0.13.1

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1], 'y':[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]})

In [3]: print pd.factorize(pd.lib.fast_zip([df.x, df.y]))[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d98d985f2794> in <module>()
----> 1 print pd.factorize(pd.lib.fast_zip([df.x, df.y]))[0]

/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.fast_zip (pandas/lib.c:8026)()

SystemError: numpy/core/src/multiarray/iterators.c:370: bad argument to internal function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `df.x.values` and `df.y.values` instead, in order to access the `np.ndarray` objects needed in `pd.lib.fast_zip()`:

```
print(pd.factorize(pd.lib.fast_zip([df.x.values, df.y.values]))[0])
```