# Numbering Groups In Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way in Pandas to number groups in a DataFrame, based on column values? If my frame looks like this

```
  Column1 Column2  Column3
0       A       X       23
1       A       X       45
2       A       Y       32
3       A       Y       53
4       A       Y       67
5       B       X       85
6       B       Y       12
7       B       Y       94
```

What I'd like to be able to do is something like

```
df.group_numbers(['Column1', 'Column2'])

  Column1 Column2  Column3  GroupNumber
0       A       X       23            1
1       A       X       45            1
2       A       Y       32            2
3       A       Y       53            2
4       A       Y       67            2
5       B       X       85            3    
6       B       Y       12            4
7       B       Y       94            4
```

Comment: This is a bit like a multi-column factorize: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453465/multi-column-factorize-in-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in `ajcr`'s comment, `pd.factorize` is the way to go. In your case you can add the two columns to quickly create an array of keys by adding the two columns with some delimiter between. The delimiter is to avoid confusing pairs such as `ab, c` and `a, bc` as suggested by `DSM`.

```
df['GroupNumber'] = pd.factorize(df.Column1 + ' ' + df.Column2)
```

It's still faster than using `pd.lib.fast_zip`.

Comment: I think I like your earlier answer better.  This one would confuse "AB","C" and "A","BC".

Comment: Yes, good point. I was focusing too much on the data presented. I've updated the answer.